# PHP - send an image which is stored in memory with redis to user

Tags: php, redis

This is how I serve images to clients so far:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $imgName . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($imgPath));
header('Cache-control: max-age='.(60*60*24*365));
readfile($imgPath);
```

now I want to store them in memory with redis and serve them to the clients from there.

I tried:

```
$image = $redis->get('bla');
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="bla.jpg"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($image));
header('Cache-control: max-age='.(60*60*24*365));
readfile($image);
```

The image is stored correctly with redis, I tested doing:

```
file_put_contents('bla.jpg', $redis->get('bla'));
```

How to send the with redis stored image correctly?

Comment: Surely you want to write `$image` to the output buffer instead of `readfile($image)` at the end of your script?  Something like `file_put_contents("php://output", $image);`

Comment: "Surely you want to write $image to the output buffer instead of readfile($image) at the end of your script" no I don't know what's all the difference. Can you explain what exactly file_put_contents("php://output" is doing? I found out that I can just echo $image after setting the headers, is it the same or does file_put_contents("php://output" have any advantages?

Comment: Yes that should work too.

Comment: Alright I'll keep it with echo, thanks!